# Number of bingo draws to construct sample space without overlap

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume a bingo draw consists of $30$ unique random numbers from $1-75$ inclusive. How many draws $(N)$ would you need to be $90\%$ certain that there exist a subset of draws $K$ such that the $K$ draws have all $75$ numbers covered, and that they are uniformly distributed?

Comment: uniformly distributed is a hypothesis or something you want to achieve? If it is the latter how do you define it? Same number of each number?

Comment: That's correct, same number of each number.

Comment: Well in this case I do not think the "uniformly distributed" constraint in the subset K adds any constraint. You will take one number of each kind in your subset K. Right? Or am I misunderstanding

Comment: I have a large set of bingo draws currently. I am wondering if it is large enough to be pretty certain (90%) I can use K of these N draws such that the K draws cover all numbers exactly once.

Comment: Just to verify: a subset of $K$ draws would cover $30K$ numbers (counting multiple occurrences).  So it is impossible to cover each of 75 numbers exactly ONCE.  But 5 draws can conceivably cover each number twice, and 10 draws can conceivably cover each number 4 times, etc.  So the only possible solutions have $K = 5n$ for integer $n$ to cover the 75 numbers $30K/75 = 2n$ times per number.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Oh, yes that makes sense. So remove the no multiple requirement. I will edit the question.